# More elegant way to create a list of lines from BeautifulSoup.findAll

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am writing a web parser using BeautifulSoup. I create a list of lines generated with `bs.findAll(text=True)`, and then split line for line and apply my logic there. `html_payload` is an arbitrary webpage.

The code I've got so far works, but it's not very pretty, and makes me think there must be a better, more elagant way of writing it.

```py
    data_to_parse = BeautifulSoup(html_payload)
    lines_to_parse = []

    d = data_to_parse.findAll(text=True)
    for line in d:
        for line2 in line.strip().split('\n'):
            if line2:
                lines_to_parse.append(line2)

    for line in lines_to_parse:
        pass # here's where I start analyzing results
```

Is there anyone who can suggest a better way of solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [get all the text at once](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) and split it into lines:

```
data_to_parse = BeautifulSoup(html_payload)
for line in data_to_parse.get_text().split("\n"):
    pass  # ... do something
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of list comprehension:

```
lines_to_parse = [line2 for line in data_to_parse.findAll(text=True) for line2 in line.strip().split('\n') if line2]
```

Or, you can actually combine collecting and analyzing step:

```
d = data_to_parse.findAll(text=True)
for line in d:
     for line2 in line.strip().split('\n'):
         if line2:
             # analyze here
```

Or, keeping in mind that you are not heavily using `BeautifulSoup`, [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) might help you to collect the data into the list, take a look.

Hope that helps.

Comment: @downvoter, what is the reason for a downvote? We are here to help and give advices: having a better advice in the thread is not a reason for downvoting.